# Our manifest mentions ItemType Message but ItemSend event is invoked for appointments as well

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are developing a web-technologies Outlook Add-in that works with Office 365.

We are using the ItemSend event.

In our Outlook App manifest, we have:

```
<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
</Rule>
```

ItemType is an enumeration that has 'Message' and 'Appointment'.

However our app is invoked for appointments as well, which is unexpected.  The mailboxItem.itemType is showing "appointment" in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The `Rule` section you have in your manifest extract above does not control the ItemSend feature. It is meant for another completely separate feature.

Currently, there's no way to restrict ItemSend (on send) events to messages only.
As a workaround, you can skip validation by using `if (Office.context.mailbox.item.itemType == Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Appointment)`.

If this is not a sufficient workaround, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add a feature request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]